# function for filtering excel cells using python pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm trying to filter an excel sheet based on some conditions using function
so when ever you enter the name of the staff it will filter based on the name

```
def small_Purchase_Filter(staff_name):
    name_filter = pd.DataFrame((list["Procurement Staff assigned to PR"] == staff_name) & (master_list["Threshold"]== "Small Purchase") & (list["PR Status"]=="Completed") & (master_list["received"] != "open"))
    return name_filter
```

Note : this code

`name_filter = pd.DataFrame((list["Procurement Staff assigned to PR"] == staff_name) & (master_list["Threshold"]== "Small Purchase") & (list["PR Status"]=="Completed") & (master_list["received"] != "open"))`

it was ruining just fine until i put it inside a function now all the result of the sheet is NaN

I hope i was clear enough and thanks

Comment: are list, master_list the names of the sheets in the excel dataframe? you might need to pass the dataframe to your function as well, rather than just the staff name that you need?

Comment: you might look into this before posting; [mcve]. no way to check for us now.